# RecyclerView is not showing all of the items in the adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I implemented infinite scrolling in my `RecyclerView` by checking the item's position in `onBindViewHolder()` and whether or not more items are being requested from the `REST` service. If the item's position is less than 5 from the end of the list and a request is not currently being made for more items, then a request for more items is executed.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ItemHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.bindHolder(position);

    //debugging purposes
    //logs the current position, the size of the item list, and whether 
    //or not more items are already being retrieved from the rest service
    Log.d("ADAPTER", "position = " + position +
                     "\nmItems.size() = " + mItems.size() +
                     "\nGET_USER_FEED_IS_INACTIVE = " +
                     HTTPRequests.GET_USER_FEED_IS_INACTIVE + "\n\n");

    //query for more items if the user is less than 5 items from the end and
    //there is not already an active query
    if (position > mPolls.size() - 5 && HTTPRequests.GET_USER_FEED_IS_INACTIVE){
        HTTPRequests.GETUsersFeed();
    }
}
```

Infinite scrolling works fine if the `RecyclerView` is scrolled through slowly, but if I scroll to the end really quickly, the query grabs the next batch of items, adds them to the list, but the `RecyclerView` won't move past the item that used to be the lat item as if it's the end of the list. The crazy part is that it's clear with the logging that the list is larger than the `RecyclerView` makes it seem to appear, but it won't display the new items.

The below 4 logs are the last 4 created when I scroll to the bottom of the `RecyclerView` very quickly:

```
D/ADAPTER: position = 20
           mItems.size() = 50
           GET_USER_FEED_IS_INACTIVE = true

D/ADAPTER: position = 19
           mItems.size() = 50
           GET_USER_FEED_IS_INACTIVE = true

D/ADAPTER: position = 23
           mItems.size() = 50
           GET_USER_FEED_IS_INACTIVE = true

D/ADAPTER: position = 24
           mItems.size() = 50
           GET_USER_FEED_IS_INACTIVE = true
```

The last log shows that `onBindViewHolder()` was called for item at position 24 -- the last item received from the first query -- and at that time, `mItems.size()` is 50 -- the second batch of 25 items has been received and added to `mItems`.
However, I cannot scroll down any further past item 24.

Any ideas on why this may be happening?

.

**Update:**

Here is the code that runs when I receive the response from the `REST` service:

```
public void onResponse(String response) {
        List<Item> usersFeed = sGson.fromJson(response, new TypeToken<ArrayList<Item>>(){}.getType());

        //get the size of the adapter's list before new items are added
        int initialNumberOfItemsInAdapter = FUserFeed.sAdapter.getItemCount();

        //add new items to adapter's list
        RealmSingleton.addToBottomOfUserFeedRealm(usersFeed);

        //notify adapter of the new items
        FUserFeed.sAdapter
                 .notifyItemRangeInserted(initialNumberOfItemsInAdapter, usersFeed.size());

        //signify the end of GETUserFeed activity
        GET_USER_FEED_IS_INACTIVE = true;
        Log.d("VOLLEY", response);
}
```

**Update:**
More strange behavior -- when I navigate to another fragment and then right back to the user feed fragment, the `RecyclerView` now recognizes that there are more items in the list, so infinite scrolling starts behaving properly again. But if I scroll down very quickly again, the bug eventually reoccurs, and I have to navigate to and from another fragment to get it working again.

Comment: Have you tried `notifyDataSetChanged` instead of 'inserted'? Just in case

Comment: @StasLelyuk no, but i solved the problem. i'm not sure if i figured out the cause of the issue, but the infinite scrolling is working regardless. check out my answer

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the problem was `RealmSingleton.addToBottomOfUserFeedRealm(usersFeed)` was adding the `Item`s to my adapter's `RealmResults` list asynchronously -- a feature of `Realm`-- and I was calling `FUserFeed.sAdapter.notifyItemRangeInserted()` right after it. So, I was notifying the adapter that new items were inserted before new items were even inserted.

So what I did was `addChangeListener(RealmChangeListener)` to `mItems` and called `notifyItemRangeInserted()` within it to ensure that it's called only after `mItems` has changed.

Now it's working perfectly; no matter how fast I scroll down.

It is still weird though why it worked when I scrolled slowly. The scrolling speed doesn't affect the speed at which `Realm` asynchronously added items to `mItems`, so `notifyItemRangeInserted()` should have always been called before the items were actually added to the list. And yet, the implementation still worked if I scrolled sufficiently slowly.